# Ajax.ActionLink loading image positioning with background opacity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, loading

When I click the ajax.action link, I want to display loading image in the middle of the page with backgroung opacity.

```
<img id="image_loading" alt="" src="../../images/site/loading.gif" style="position: fixed;     
     display: none;" />
```

Here is my code

```
<nav class="ust_menu">
    <ul>
         <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "article_site", LoadingElementId = "image_loading" })</li>
         <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Contact Us", "Contact", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "article_site", LoadingElementId = "image_loading" })</li>
         <li>@Ajax.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "article_site", LoadingElementId = "image_loading" })</li>    
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I can show image without background opacity and not the position I want.
How can I show loading image in the middle of page with background opacity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To center the image:

```
<img id="image_loading" alt="" src="@Url.Content("~/content/loading.gif")" class="progress" />
```

and in CSS file:

```
.progress {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left : 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

Now if you want to do some more fancy effects you could subscribe to the `OnBegin` and `OnComplete` callbacks where you will have more control over the way the image is shown:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { 
    OnBegin = "onBegin",
    OnComplete = "onComplete",
    UpdateTargetId = "article_site"
})
```

and then:

```
function onBegin() {
    // TODO: show the progress image
}

function onComplete() {
    // TODO: hide the progress image
}
```